# iOS full-time background-service based on location tracking

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, networking, background

I'm currently writing an application which depends on location tracking and sending data about the position to the server. The problem, however, is that it has to run 24/7 and currently I'm experiencing random crashes which occur every 2-3 days. What I have done to make the application run constantly in the background is I put a NSTimer in a beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler method right iside the applicationDidEnterBackground method. The timer executes each minute and stops/starts the location service.

[Here is a sample crash log](http://pastebin.com/u7WJbgkg)

The code basically looks like this:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId = 0;

bgTaskId = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 * 60.0 target: self selector: @selector(onTick) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    [t fire];

    if (bgTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
        [app endBackgroundTask: bgTaskId];

        bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}];
```

I am using *GCDAsyncSockets* for connection purposes, each call having a timeout of approximately 30 seconds.

I'm really out of ideas, what might be the reason the crashes occur?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

This link is the doc for the multitasking and background stuff. It might hold the info we all seek.

Comment: Yea I did this an app once, you might want to use NSRunLoopCommonModes for your timer

Comment: Have you looked at the WWCD 2010 session "Using Core Location in iOS 4" and the associated sample app "Breadcrumbs"?    http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/        They describe how to use Core Location while backgrounded without using any timer tricks.

Answer (score 4):

Your timer is probably firing off AFTER the task is invalidated (after `[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining` gets to 0.

The thing is that you **can't** make the application run *constantly in the background*. If you want to execute code every once in a while, your only option is going to be using the background location API, setting that your app is using the *location* background mode in its plist.
You would be getting the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` callbacks, and you have *some time* to do some work when those methods are called.

See the Apple documentation regarding background modes: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

And the location-awarness manual: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497