# Periodic background location - using desired accuracy and distance filter

Tags: ios, cllocation

I am trying to use this technique in iOS7 to get a location every x seconds - [Periodic iOS background location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates).

In my didUpdateLocations:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];
    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:9999];
}
```

When i run this, i seem to get a loop. setDesiredAccuracy: - i think this forces an update itself, on change. This is why I am getting a loop, would this be right? When I comment these out, it acts like I expect it too. Is there anyway to stop it get location when i set these?

Comment: The approach you are taking is wrong due to some changes in multitasking in iOS 7
This approach will not work as you are expecting : 1) Increasing the value of distanceFilter property doesn't result in battery saving because gps still has to keep figuring your location. 2) In iOS 7 background time is non - contiguous. 3) You might take into account significantChangeLocation services. 4) Apart from your soution in iOS 7 you can't start UIBackgroundModes - location from background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should set some kind of time/date stamp on how often you call "`setDesiredAccuracy`".  If you call it once, don't call it again for some certain period of time.

something like:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastResetOfAccuracy = [lastResetTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if(secondsSinceLastResetOfAccuracy > 60 * 60) // one hour
    {    
        [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];
        [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:9999];
        lastResetTime = [NSDate date]; // new "time stamp"
    }
}
```

Comment: inside the if condition you need to place `secondsSinceLastResetOfAccuracy  * -1` I suppose as `secondsSinceLastResetOfAccuracy ` will be a minus value according to this scenario and if condition will never met if we don't multiply it by `-1`. I mean when the variable `lastResetTime` is from the past `timeIntervalSinceNow` will return seconds in minus value.