# Using core motion in background by update location every second

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, core-motion

My application is under study if I can do it because there is some issues I do not know if I Can do it     .

- Is there any solution to capture device movement with Core Motion when the screen is locked or the app in background ?
  I know there is some background modes like audio - location update - voip ...etc .
  How to use accelerometer events in background by update location every second
  "keep my app alive"
- when the device is switch off and going to switch on can I run the app in background automatically ?

thank you for helping me

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083032/coremotion-updates-in-background-state

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I want to use update location to keep my app alive