# How does Knock to unlock reliably detect knocks even on sleeping phones when in the background?

Tags: ios, background, core-motion

Here is the app: http://www.knocktounlock.com/

Which leads me to believe the prior threads on this topic([CoreMotion updates in background state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083032/coremotion-updates-in-background-state)) are no longer accurate because it does indeed work reliably even when your phone is in sleep mode and locked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on their webpage, this is how it works. There is an app on the Mac. When you wake up the Mac screen, before unlocking, the Map app sends a BLE notification to the unlock app on the phone. BLE notifications can start iphone apps in the background.  The iPhone app starts monitoring the accelerometer and send a BLE notification back to the Mac when you knock.

Comment: My client has a app that imports your gcal and auto schedules your to-do list in the gaps of your schedule. Our vision for giving our app a edge was to add a feature that enables users to knock on their device even if its sleeping or they have another app open and they would get a push notification telling them what they are suppose to be doing right now.Is this possible?

Comment: that sounds like a brand new question, not a comment.  but the answer is no.