# Getting the location data and send to server in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have read the documentation about the core location , and am trying to understand whats allowed and what is not .

We need to get locations from a costumer every 30 minutes,and send to our servers, when the app is in background.
One option is the Significant location change, but i have read its not accurate .
What are my options , and is it possible ?

thanks .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512015/can-i-send-users-current-location-to-server-when-app-is-in-background/21512133#21512133)

Answer (score 0):

There are no official way. Also remember that the user's consent. And it charged the battery.

If the app in the background, you have a few minutes to perform actions (about 10 minutes). Facebook somehow manages to get them started again this "10 minutes".

Comment: what is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates

Comment: oh nice solution. I had not seen befor. 
is the location needed when the user is in a store or not. If the location is to be determined within a store use beacons (http://estimote.com/).

Comment: In iOS7 you can use the ```fetch``` background mode to download and upload data periodically. This goes beyond the 10 minutes limit. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512015/can-i-send-users-current-location-to-server-when-app-is-in-background/21512133#21512133)