# IOS inaccurate GPS timestamps

Tags: ios, gps, timestamp, clock

i'm trying to log every GPS update from an iphone, i'm getting unstable refresh times with:

```
NSTimeInterval lastEventInterval = [lastLocation.timestamp
timeIntervalSinceDate:previousLocation.timestamp];
```

The result:

```
Internal Iphone 4S 1Hz GPS

981ms  new position
1015ms  new position
1610ms  new position
872ms  new positon
1023ms new position


External Bluetooth 10 hz GPS

122ms new position
191ms new position
325ms new position
98ms  new position
166ms new position
```

So with Android and location.getTime() i get perfectly accurate refresh

```
Internal Motorola Rarz 1Hz GPS

1000ms  new position
1000ms  new position
1000ms  new position
1000..


External Bluetooth 10 hz GPS

100ms new position
100ms new position
100ms new position
100ms..
```

Answer (score 0):

The following question might help out your specific problem. check the @pcoving answer. it seems to be right answer. Instead of copying his answer here, I am giving you link to check.

[Periodic iOS background location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates)

Comment: i don't understand where can help me a code target for a LOW FREQUENCY refresh  when i'm looking for a HIGH FREQUENCY refresh