# iOS Background location tracking fails on test devices

Tags: ios, background, location

Based on this [example application](https://github.com/voyage11/Location/tree/master/Location)
and this Stackoverflow post: [Periodic iOS background location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates), I have managed to create a working implementation for periodic background location tracking.

Everything works well on the device and I install the application from Xcode, but to every tester I send the application to via *crashlytics* the app still times out in the background.

Does it have to do anything with debug/release mode or provisioning profiles?

Comment: What timeout are you using ? 180 seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use applicationDidEnterBackground method to get update location in background mode. I have download your source from github, in this there is no implemented in below method :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
```

You have to use like this :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

For more details you can refer the link : 
http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried the following in Appdelegate?

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
     //`locationManager` is object of `CLLocationManager` 
}
```

Comment: My friend have a same problem. So he tried this in appdelegate and now app works fine