# How to get location periodically and send location to server in background ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, ios9

I want my app to get the location every 15 minutes and send the location information to a server.
In the server, I compared locations and send a response to the client as a notification (almost like a push notification but on my server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CLLocation Managers authorization to *requestAlwaysAuthorization* to fetch location continuously (even when your app is in the background.)

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

Note: *requestAlwaysAuthorization* is battery intensive and apple reviewers will expect a very strong reason for using this for your app to be approved. Also, make sure that “location update” under the required Background Modes is checked.

You can use a *NSTimer* to determine 15 mins and get location from the above *CLLocationManager*.

After that, you can use a background task to update location to the server.

You can follow the below links if you have any doubts:
http://www.creativeworkline.com/2014/12/core-location-manager-ios-8-fetching-location-background/
http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7
[Periodic iOS background location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates)

Comment: thank you very much... i use https://github.com/voyage11/Location and it help me... hope to accept from apple reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25).

From the guide there are some key points, you may interested in the following section from the apple documentation.

> The significant-change location service is highly recommended for apps
>   that do not need high-precision location data. With this service,
>   location updates are generated only when the user’s location changes
>   significantly; thus, it is ideal for social apps or apps that provide
>   the user with noncritical, location-relevant information. If the app
>   is suspended when an update occurs, the system wakes it up in the
>   background to handle the update. If the app starts this service and is
>   then terminated, the system relaunches the app automatically when a
>   new location becomes available. This service is available in iOS 4 and
>   later, and it is available only on devices that contain a cellular
>   radio.

For implementation details take a look [Getting location events background(ios)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)