# Running App in Background (iOS)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process, background-service

How to run whole app in background? 
I'm using location service. My aim is to detect, connect and write to BLE when my app is on background state. So I have 2 option, run whole app in background or execute function when I enter background state. But when I try to call function, it doesn't worked.

Comment: tried writing in "func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {}"  ???

Comment: go through the document https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Please check below post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates

Comment: I've tried. I entered background state and then i can print something, but when i want to call another complex function, it's not working @DHEERAJ

Comment: I've tried that also, but thats not what i want. @Shubhambairagi

Comment: Can you show your code?  Have you read the section on background operation in the core Bluetooth programming guide?