# iOS get local notifications with app closed

Tags: ios, swift3, notifications, location

At my app, I allow Background Mode: location

I get a notification always I pass through certain places which are stores in the app, be it backgrounded or foregrounded.

The problem is: I want the app to send notifications to me when I pass through these places even when the app is closed (terminated).

What approach should I use to get this done?

PS: I'm using `CoreLocation`'s `CLLocationManager` to notify in foreground and in background, but closed it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using geofencing region monitoring?

Comment: And also make sure that you have added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your info.plist

Comment: I'm using the AlwaysUsage, my code is similar to the second answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates

Comment: Ah... You can't have location updates with this when you app is (terminated).  You can use geofencing it works even if your app is terminated.

Comment: Hi @DcCoO Did you make it work this ? and with android ?