# Need to start location updates in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, background, core-location

I've an use case where i need to start location updates once I detected region entry. I've tried all possible options available in location programming.

From my experience, i was able to get the deferred location updates working when i launch the app and put it in the background, it wont start deferring location updates automatically when the app is launched in the background due to region entry. Same is with both the standard and significant location update options.

Can someone help me or provide me any references that help me initiate location updates when app is launched in the background due to some events like region entry or silent remote notification?

Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following are some links ,i hope it will help you:

[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

[Getting user location every n minutes after app goes to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235203/getting-user-location-every-n-minutes-after-app-goes-to-background?rq=1)

[iOS Not the typical background location tracking timer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377750/ios-not-the-typical-background-location-tracking-timer-issue)

[iOS long-running background timer with "location" background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650139/ios-long-running-background-timer-with-location-background-mode)

[iOS full-time background-service based on location tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706265/ios-full-time-background-service-based-on-location-tracking)

Check this link for iOS 7:
[Start Location Manager in iOS 7 from background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901583/start-location-manager-in-ios-7-from-background-task)